# Binding the dataset from xml files cannot get the data

Tags: c#, xml, vb.net, visual-studio

I need to bind the dataset from xml files after sorting it. I followed the example from [Loading a DataSet from XML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/dataset-datatable-dataview/loading-a-dataset-from-xml). But I got the error indexOutOfRangeEXception. The dataset has no table. Would someone tell me how to solve the problem.

I am able to add the node into the xml on another function in my code.  It proved the file path is correct.

Thanks in advance.

there is my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <EmailList>
   <EmailAddress>
     <ID>90</ID>
     <DisplayName>TesterA</DisplayName>
     <Email>TesterA@gmail.ca</Email>   
   </EmailAddress>
   <EmailAddress>
      <ID>75</ID>
      <DisplayName>TesterB</DisplayName>
      <Email>TesterB@gmail.ca</Email>   
   </EmailAddress>
  <EmailAddress>
      <ID>91</ID>
     <DisplayName>TesterC</DisplayName>
     <Email>TesterC@gmail.ca</Email>    
   </EmailAddress>
  </EmailList>
```

There is my code:

```
  Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet
    ds.ReadXml(fileName, XmlReadMode.ReadSchema)
    If ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then
        Dim dv As DataView = ds.Tables(0).DefaultView
        dv.Sort = "DisplayName"
        grdEmailList.DataSource = dv
        grdEmailList.DataBind()
    End If
```

Comment: if `ds.Tables` has no table, then checking for `.Rows.Count` on `ds.Tables(0)` will yield `indexOutOfRangeEXception`. Make sure that `ds.ReadXml(fileName, XmlReadMode.ReadSchema)` works as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `XmlReadMode.ReadSchema` to `XmlReadMode.Auto` or remove it. Your XML doesnot contains schema.